# Android Studio - How to set text for TextInputLayout programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-textinputlayout

To set text for views like EditText, I simply need to use `setText("text")` function, but I can't do that to TextInputLayout. How do I set text for TextInputLayout?

Comment: `TextInputLayout` is a layout that should wrap a `TexInputEditText` .. You can't `setText` on the layout, but you can on the latter

Answer (score 0):

Just have to set the the to the `TexInputEditText`.

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        ..>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Something like:

```
textInputLayout.getEditText().setText("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

To set text in TextInputLayout you'd need to create an EditText within it.
Something like:

```
TextInputLayout parent = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        EditText editText = new EditText;
        editText.setText("the text");
        editText.setLayoutParams(new TextInputLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        parent.addView(editText);
        }
```